# Where are the view state change events in WinJs?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, winjs

In Windows 8 when the view state changes from snapped to filled to full screen;

How can I catch these events and respond to them with WinJs ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/04/19/getting-the-most-out-of-your-pixels-adapting-to-view-state-changes.aspx) blog post on how to catch view state changes.  Basically the recommendation boils down to catching the resize event and then checking the view state like this:

```
 window.addEventListener("resize", onResize);


function onResize() { 
    // Update view for the new window size 
    updateView(); 
} 

function updateView() { 
    // Query for the current view state 
    var myViewState = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.value; 

    var viewStates = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewState; 
    var statusText; 

    // Assign text according to view state 
    switch (myViewState) { 
        case viewStates.snapped: 
            statusText = "This app is snapped!"; 
            break; 
        case viewStates.filled: 
            statusText = "This app is in filled state!"; 
            break; 
        case viewStates.fullScreenLandscape: 
            statusText = "This app is full screen landscape!"; 
            break; 
        case viewStates.fullScreenPortrait: 
            statusText = "This app is full screen portrait!"; 
            break; 
        default: 
            statusText = "Error: Invalid view state returned."; 
            break; 
    }
```

If you look in the Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 RC for Windows 8 [template for Javascript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh758331.aspx#handling_view_state) you will see something like this in navigator.js:

```
window.onresize = this._resized.bind(this);

_resized: function(args) {
    if (this.pageControl && this.pageControl.updateLayout) {
        this.pageControl.updateLayout.call(this.pageControl, this.pageElement, appView.value, this.lastViewstate);
    }
    this.lastViewstate = appView.value;
},

//*page*.js

updateLayout: function (element, viewState, lastViewState) {
     /// <param name="element" domElement="true" />
     var listView = element.querySelector(".itemslist").winControl;
     if (lastViewState !== viewState) {
          if (lastViewState === appViewState.snapped || viewState === appViewState.snapped) {
               var handler = function (e) {
               listView.removeEventListener("contentanimating", handler, false);
               e.preventDefault();
          }
          listView.addEventListener("contentanimating", handler, false);
          var firstVisible = listView.indexOfFirstVisible;
          this._initializeLayout(listView, viewState);
          if (firstVisible >= 0 && listView.itemDataSource.list.length > 0) {
                listView.indexOfFirstVisible = firstVisible;
           }
       }
   }
},

_initializeLayout: function (listView, viewState) {

    if (viewState === appViewState.snapped) {
        listView.layout = new ui.ListLayout();
    } else {
        listView.layout = new ui.GridLayout();
    }
},
```

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465371.aspx#snap_ux) msdn page you can also use media queries when view state changes affect the CSS properties or layout specified in the CSS.  For all other changes onResize should be used.

Comment: Another option is to use mediaselectors:
var f = matchMedia("all and (-ms-view-stated: snapped)");
f.addListener(myHandlerFn);

Comment: @DominicHopton You can catch the state change, but the blog post I linked points out that the size will not have changed when that event fires, so if you have any size dependent UI then you pretty much have to wait for the `onResize` event.  Catching `onResize` always works.

Comment: That was consumer preview recommendation; this is no longer the case in RP & RTM.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're looking.  The RC template for js still uses onResize.

Comment: @DominicHopton Maybe I'm missing something.  How is your code more authoritative than the RC template?

Comment: I didn't say it was more authoritative. Depending on your scenario, code types, and needs, using a matching media selector may well be a justifiable option. In my usage, I'm seeing that things are fine.

Comment: So "That was consumer preview recommendation; this is no longer the case in RP & RTM." is simply your opinion and has no reference?  The msdn still recommends using onResize().

Comment: I was making the statement that the article you linked to was consumer preview. Consumer preview vs RP is a radical difference. Even the API for this case changed between then and now. I would, personally recommend running the code for your scenario and seeing what fits.

For my usage, I have built a flexible layout that adjusts as needed and behaves great -- I don't need the size for my scenario. In those situation matchmedia works, and allows a slightly more "standards" API rather than relying on WinRT.

Comment: I found documentation on when to use media queries and have added it to my answer.